# understanding pointers c++

Tags: c++, pointers

When i write this code:

```
Animal *p;
Animal b;
p = &b;
```

In the first line when I am creating a pointer. Does a new object of Animal is created or only when you write the second line?

Thanks.

Comment: Only when you write the second line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first line, a pointer is created but it doesn't point to anything yet. In the second line you create an actual `Animal` object.

Comment: and if i make a poiner as private and inside a function i create an actual object and put it into the pointer just like i wrote in the question when i exit the function does the new object terminated?

Comment: @adir yes the destructor is called when it goes out of scope and your pointer will then become invalid.  They are called pointers because they point to locations in memory they aren't created instances unles you allocate them on the heap by using the new operator in which case you must remember to also delete them or you will have memory leaks!

Answer (score 9):

When you declare a pointer [and the declaration is a definition], space is only allocated for a pointer, there is no `Animal` object created.

If you don't initialize the pointer you can't use it in any way except to point it at a valid `Animal` object or to assign it the special "null pointer value" to indicate that the pointer doesn't point at a valid object. You can't even test whether it's actually pointing at a valid `Animal` object at all.

It is always advisable to initialize pointers either to null or to a valid object as soon as you create them, so I would recommend either:

```
Animal* p = 0; // or = NULL
Animal u;
p = &u;
```

or better:

```
Animal u;
Animal* p = &u;
```

Answer (score 4):

`Animal *p;` creates a pointer, `Animal b;` creates an animal.

Answer (score 1):

A new object is created on the stack when that method is created and goes away when the method returns.  It is going to crash your application if you return that value from the method and try to use it since the stack memory will have been deallocated as a part of returning from the method.

Comment: The language does not guarantee a crash, though. Trying to access an object after its lifetime has ended yields *undefined behavior*, which may or may not lead to strange results, including crashes.

Comment: True, but for all practical purposes, one can *expect* a crash.  To even argue that this is a usable technique is not valuable to a programmer at his level.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the op question but scope issues can arise if you have pointers to instance variables so it's a valid point on pointers ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
// create a pointer to an animal object and initialize it to NULL
//Animal* p; // Bad!  Do not do this
Animal* pA = NULL; // Much better

Animal a; // creates an Animal object on the stack (local scope)

Animal pA = &a; // sets pA to point to the location of a
```

Now when `a` goes out of scope, `pA` will still point to that memory location.  If you try to access it, bad things can (and will) happen.